# настройка перенапрвления с исключением

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите сообразить правило перенаправления с исключением файла `robots.txt` в `.htaccess`.

Сайт переехал с `http` на `https`. Обратились к тех поддержки хостинга и они прописали правило перенаправления с `http` на `https` в файле `.htaccess` следующего содержания:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} !=https
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Перенапрвления начало работать. Но в панели управления была обнаружена ошибка:

> Сервер отвечает редиректом на запрос /robots.txt

Далее тех.поддержка хостинга сказала следующие:

> Для исправления ситуации необходимо задать верные правила перенаправления с исключениями.

Помогите их задать

Comment: Виктория, лучше внести [правку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/478544/edit) в вопрос, чем писать нечитабельные комментарии

Comment: @NickVolynkin так Виктория уже сама внесла правку в вопрос

Comment: @korytoff: ого, похоже что я просмотрел. Удаляю правку.

Answer (score 2):

Я не понимаю в чем проблема использовать [документацию](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)?

[Гугл](https://www.google.ru/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=htaccess+robots.txt&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=lRyBVqCbFe_67gS9pws) тоже многое знает. Ну и на `SO` полно [ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452211/htaccess-rewrite-www-to-non-www-except-robots-txt).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots\.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} !=https
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```